# Mapping values in SQL select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, lets for simplicity call it `Plant`,
with three columns: `id`, `name`, `category`. 
This the most simplified example, so please do not worry about normalization ...

```
+-------+--------+------------+
| id    | name   | category   |
+-------+--------+------------+
| 1     | orange | fruits     |
| 2     | banana | fruits     |
| 3     | tomato | vegetables |
| 4     | kaokao | NULL       |
+-------+--------+------------+
```

If want to have a query which returns:

- '`Fruit Plant`' instead of '`fruits`'
- '`Vegetable Plant`' instead of '`vegetables`'
- '`unknown`' instead of `NULL`s

So the return should be:

```
+-------+--------+-----------------+
| id    | name   | category        |
+-------+--------+-----------------+
| 1     | orange | Fruit Plant     |
| 2     | banana | Fruit Plant     |
| 3     | tomato | Vegetable Plant |
| 4     | kaokao | unknown         |
+-------+--------+-----------------+
```

How can I do this mapping for select values ?

I am using mysql, if this may have a special `IF` keyword/function in mysql

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `case` expression:

```
select
    id,
    name,
    case 
        when category = 'fruits' then 'Fruit Plant'
        when category = 'vegetables' then 'Vegetable Plant'
        when category is null then 'unknown'
    end as category
from Plant
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know that there is a case block in mysql. How can I set a default to it for all other values other than fruits and vegetables and nulls ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir . . . use `else`.

Answer (score 23):

use  `case` function (with **else** statement for default values) :

```
select id, name, 
case category
   when 'vegetables' then 'Vegetable Plant'
   when 'fruits' then 'Fruit Plant'
   when is null then 'unknown'
   else 'default values'
end
from Plant
```